# How to replace a specific column data to its z-scores in a data set in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a numeric dataset and I want to calculate the z score for 'KM' column and replace the original values with the z score values. I'm new to python and please help.

```
 KM CC  Doors   Gears   Quarterly_Tax   Weight  Guarantee_Period
46986   2000    3   5   210 1165    3
72937   2000    3   5   210 1165    3
38500   2000    3   5   210 1170    3
31461   1800    3   6   100 1185    12
32189   1800    3   6   100 1185    3
23000   1800    3   6   100 1185    3
18739   1800    3   6   100 1185    3
34000   1800    3   5   100 1185    3
21716   1600    3   5   85  1105    18
64359   1600    3   5   85  1105    3
67660   1600    3   5   85  1105    3
43905   1600    3   5   100 1170    3
```

Comment: @Dex, it gives an error.

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the error?

Comment: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: This shouldn't occur really with scipy's z-score function. Can you please post your code? I'd be able to answer better then.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for you

```
from scipy import stats
df["KM"] = df["KM"].apply(stats.zscore)
```